# How to get selected date in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a question about [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

How can i get selected date in "beforeShowDay" function?
I see only one arg in this function: date. This is the day for which BeforeShowDay called. I need to get the day which is selected in datepicker.

Thanks!